# How to add external script to vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, web, vue.js, vue-component

I need your help very much...
I have a Vue component and endpoint which gives me a script with a small menu and that script includes some actions.
So, after my script is loaded its actions don't work on a page and I don't know why. 
Below the example code:

```
<template>
  <div id="menu"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // here I get a script which contains menu bar with actions
    // css and styles 
    this.$http.get("https://endpointwithscript.com/menu").then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        //in that case script doesn't work. Eg click
        var div = document.getElementById("menu")
        div.innerHTML += response.body;
        document.appendChild(div);
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

If I insert my downloaded script that way :

```
mounted () {
    this.$http.get("https://endpointwithscript.com/menu").then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        document.write(response.body);
      }
    })
  }
```

then script works but another html elements are overridden by that script and not displayed.
How to download script, insert it on a page and keep all functionality ?
Thank you!

Comment: what does that script contain?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim tag <script type="text/javascript">, css and I guess some html elements . Don't remember exactly

Comment: so you could build a component using that content, import it and use it in this code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, it's a good idea. But how to build it properly. I can use var div = document.getElementById("menu")
        div.innerHTML += response.body;
        document.appendChild(div); but then actions don't work

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim or document.write(response.body); but then everything inside downloaded script works but another components's templates not displayed

Comment: could you provide the content of that script and the project structure ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I can provide it tomorrow. Will it be ok ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim https://drive.google.com/open?id=18mjsjAIB0du15nBn3Sxj5tikKAdsHY3n this is the script sample

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Google formatted it a bit but don't pay attention on it. Content is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your external script into `Mounted()`

```
mounted() {
  let yourScript= document.createElement('script')
  yourScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://endpointwithscript.com/menu')
  document.head.appendChild(yourScript)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="menu"></div>`
`var div = document.getElementById("menu")`

You are grabbing the element by ID, but gave it a class instead. Change the div to be `<div id="menu"></div>`

Comment: Thanks. But it's only a typo.

Comment: Can you try using the `v-html` directive? 

`<span v-html="script"></span>`

Add the `script` property to component data, then when you fetch the script assign it to that property and the component should update.

Comment: @BrandonLyons  Boussadjra Brahim is right. The idea to display the content and keep event functionality .

Answer (score 0):

You could use v-html to include HTML-Code into a specific tag.

It seems the only way to implement a working script is by defining a new script element.

This worked for me here 
https://jsfiddle.net/nh475cq2/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted () {
  this.$http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blurrryy/8f7e9b6a74d1455b23989a7d5b094f3f/raw/921937ea99ff233dfc78add22e18868b32cd11c0/Test").then(res => {
  if(res.status === 200) {
    let scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.innerHTML = res.body;
    document.body.appendChild(scr);
  }
  })
  }
})
```